# The output for floats in list of tuples

Tags: python, tuples, output

I have the list of sorted tuples, containing floats. But when I try to output the floats (without commas and brackets) it output separate tuples BUT with brackets and commas, which I do not need.
This is the part of the code:

```
data=[tuple1, tuple2, tuple3, tuple4]
a=sorted(data, key = lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
b="\n".join(map(str,a))
print(b)
```

Comment: can you share some data sample?

Comment: What is your actual *and desired* output for a given input? Are you looking for *flattening* the list-of-tuples-of-floats to just a list-of-floats and join that?

Comment: Something like this:  41.173 77.23 41.6715 78.117
41.173 78.117 41.6715 79.004
41.6715 77.23 42.17 78.117
41.6715 78.117 42.17 79.004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
data=[tuple1, tuple2, tuple3, tuple4]
s=''
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in a[i]:
        s += str(j)

print(s)
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, Webo. Note that this prints all data concatenated, which is probably not want the OP wants. Although the question does not clearly specify the expected output, so we don't know for sure (the question should be clarified). But for floats the output of your code would be pretty useless. Besides, this code is very un-Pythonic. The one-liner given by deadshot in the other answer would be more common, IMHO.

Comment: No, Webo, thank you, it gives the output in one line

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, x)) for x in a))
```